# How to use TypeScript in RxJs (BehaviourSubject) for strict type checking?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs, rxjs5

I am trying to create a BehaviourSubject using RxJs. Here in this code

```
import { BehaviourSubject } from 'rxjs';

const name = new BehaviourSubject("Dog");

// Here in the subscribe callback, I am using TypeScript to specify the argument type should be string.
name.subscribe((name: string):void => {console.log(name)});
name.next("cat"); //cat
```

I want to restrict these below calls, as I need to pass a string as an argument in the above mentioned subscribe callback.

```
name.next(5); // This will print 5
name.next({a:5,b:{c:10}}); // This will print the object
name.next(true); // This will print true
```

Is there any way to restrict the below calls which do not have valid arguments in the subscribe callback?

Comment: So the BehaviourSubject should only accept the above 3 types as the input?

Comment: +1 for the miqh's answer. Also, if you use TS, you can use `--strict` compiler option to enable strict type checking. Check the details [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the type definition of [BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject), notice that the class accepts a generic type parameter (i.e. `BehaviorSubject<T>`).

In your example, you can stipulate that the inner value is of a `string` type by creating a parameterised version of `BehaviorSubject`, specifically:

```
const name = new BehaviorSubject<string>("Dog");
```

In doing so, you should get the type-checking applied to the subsequent usages of `next()` and `subscribe()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type alias for your `BehaviourSubject`, as it accepts a type parameter as part of the generic.

```
interface NameSubjectObj {
  a: number;
  b: {
    c: number 
  }
}

type NameSubject = string | boolean | NameSubjectObj;

const name = new BehaviourSubject<NameSubject>("Dog");
```

This will ensure that the above `BehaviourSubject` will accept those 3 types that are specified.